# Merge Excel files having same columns into one excel file using SSIS

Tags: business-intelligence, ssis

Can any one help me out how can i merge excel files having same columns which are saved in one folder to one destination excel file using SQL Server Integration services(SSIS) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an Excel source for each of your files an a "union all" task to join them, so if you have 20 rows on your first excel and 30 on the second, you will end up with 50 rows:

[image]

to set the source and destination paths, just double click each of the tasks and set the connection manager

EDIT:

example of how to read an excel file [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server-2005-using-integration-services/205)

Comment: Thanks Diego. But i am new to SSIS. Where can i get step by step procedure to achieve above task

Comment: that is the step by step procedure :) I edited my answer with an example of reading an excel file, just do it twice

Comment: What if there are 100 excel files? Creating 100 excel sources is a lengthy procedure. Is there a better way to append data of all 100 excel files to 1 excel file using SSIS?

Comment: no, then you need to use a foreach loop container class to loop the files, get the file path on a variable and your excel source will read from this variable

Comment: Thanks. I know very basics of SSIS, but can u brief me the procedure used to do this task? U can mail me if u have any docs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11524/discussion-between-vikas-kunte-and-diego)