# ssis cannot read file if not open

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS and I found a solution on this site that was extremely helpful about how to loop through Excel file and load them into a database. You can see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package?answertab=active#tab-top).

The weird thing is that the solution will only work if I have the Excel files open.  Has anyone encountered something like this before?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens if the file is not open (what error)? Generally speaking, when Excel opens a file, it opens an exclusive lock and the file and any other process that attempts to touch it gets rejected.

Comment: What do you mean open?  Do you mean having them open in Excel when you're trying to read them?  If so, I've never seen anything like that.