# SSIS Error : [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "component "Excel Source" (14)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA"

Tags: ssis, ssi

I've gone through this URL:

[How to loop through Excel files and load them into a database using SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package)

And I followed the same steps mentioned there but I got this warning:

```
[Excel Source [14]] Warning: The external columns for component 
"Excel Source" (14) are out of synchronization with the data source 
columns. The column "state" needs to be added to the external columns.
The external column "state " (27) needs to be removed from the external 
columns.
```

and this error:

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "component "Excel Source" (14)" failed validation 
and returned    validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found with this error, it is sometimes fixed by simply double clicking on each of the components, viewing the columns and various transformations, then pressing OK.  I then save and re-run and it works.  Make sure no red x's are lingering around or any other warnings.

Comment: Not opposing your point. Your answer is kind of trial and error. But whoever going to see the post in future, please refer to @Maverick checkpoints. It helped to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error is change in metadata, in my case a column name was renamed in Excel source. Verify the Excel column names and respective mapping.

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with excel source when you are working on it. There are some steps to avoid it:
1) make sure you get the Excel connection and do not change the excel file connection string or folder( physically don't move the file)
2) Check the Red Cross (X), if you see that locate the arrow in excel file source and it will show you the error code.
3) Open the excel source and check the column and check the preview
4) click ok

Note: you should not have Red Cross(X)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. 1) make sure you get the Excel connection and do not change the excel file connection string or folder( physically don't move the file) . When i does this, it works like a charm. I changed the Excel file and I changed the Connection Manager string as well to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The column's name is different. You have a space in de the name "state" vs "state ". And it's case sensitive too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unused or blank excel sheets from excel source and try to execute the package again.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you change the excel which you predefined in your connection manager during development. If you want to change the excel, make sure you do the changes in excel connection manager too(though you have configured to make use of other names).