# My excel sheet read two times

Tags: excel, ssis

I have created package by below link
[How to loop through Excel files and load them into a database using SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package)

Package work well but excel read two times and insert data in to table two time.

Please help me

Thanks,
Ramesh Rathod

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please before post anything read [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not very clear. Please try to explain in detail what you want to do, what you tried and what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the example has 2 loops, one i looping excel files and the second each sheet on the file. Are you sure you didn't set the same loop twice? Set up logging on your package, it may help you troubleshoot the problem