# ETL Using SSIS for csv files

Tags: configuration, ssis, package, etl

I am new to SSIS. I am assigned a POC development. Please help. Requirement is there are 'n' number of countries and each country will load 27 files in to 'n' number of folders. So I need to create a SSIS package to fetch the .csv files from the location and load them in staging and target tables. All countries will load same 27 files. How do I set the file connection manager dynamically. and how do i set package configuration to run it dynamically. each run should ensure the 27 files of one country gets processed. only then it has to execute the next country files. Everything has to be automated. That is at run time the files to be fetched has to be configured for a single country. can this be done? Somebody please help. I am from webmethods back ground and this is totally new.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this kind of problem in the past and did solve this issue with Creating two `Foreach Loop Container` 1) Loop the folder and 2) loop the file dynamically.You can modify this logic accordingly to your requirements. I have listed 2 references which will give you step by step process.

[How to loop through Excel files and load them into a database using SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/378129/Dynamically-Configure-Excel-in-Foreach-Loop-Contai