# check if file exists then import using script task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sas

I have static table that has the has something like this:
xy_Jan10
yz_Feb11
xx_March14
by_Aug09 
etc.
these names are static and they are stored in a table.  I am using ForEachLoop container, so first i am reading and saving all the static names that i mentioned above into an system object variable.  Next i am using the ForeachLoop containter and looping through for each of the file name and saving it into another string variable called strFileName.  So in my for each loop container, i have script task that checks first if the file exists and here is where i have the problem, for each file name that comes to the variable i want to check if that file name exist firs, if exists i want to load it into my table, if not exist then i want to check the next file name, if next file name does not exist then  i want to check the next variable name inline and so on.  I only want to load if the variable file name matches the files on the network drive, if it is not found then i want to check next one until i go through each one in my static list names.  My issue now script task stops when there is no match with the file names but i want it to go to the next variable name in the list and load it because there are a lot of other matches that are not loaded.  the script task stops at the first one where it finds non much.  Here is my script task:
please not the files i am loading are SAS files.

```
 Public Sub Main()
        '
        ' Add your code here
        '

        Dim directory As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("\\840KLM\DataMart\CPTT\Cannon")
        Dim file As FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles("*.sas7bdat")

        If file.Length > 0 Then
            Dts.Variables("User::var_IsFileExist").Value = True
        Else
            Dts.Variables("User::var_IsFileExist").Value = False
        End If
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to wrap the script task inside a ForEach loop container. There's plenty of information about how to do this on the web, or even on Stack Overflow: [How to loop through Excel files and load them into a database using SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package)

or

http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx