# Multiple xlsx files with variable

Tags: ssis

I have managed to read one xlsx file by this method:
https://dataintegrity.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/xlsx

But i need to read multiple xlsx files in a folder.
This does not seem to work. I need a solution where by a variable dynamicaly reads xlsx files in a foreach-loop container.

Comment: do you have the same exact structure, header , and sheet name in each of the xlsx files you are trying to read?

Comment: What error are you getting?   On what part of it?

Comment: Solved it by using user756519's method:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package