# Import Multiple Excel files into a table using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have two Excel files named 'First' and 'Second' in same location . 
[image]

They have same schema.

[image]

I used foreach loop counter and put Data flow task into it.

[image]

The data flow diagram looks like this:-

[image]

Here, I selected first excel file as the source....

My For Each Loop Container Editor:-

[image]

After running the SSIS package successfully the output came like this:-

[image]

Which took data only from First excel file and three times,I must have done something wrong in there,But I cant figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through Excel files and load them into a database using SSIS package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package)

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your Excel Source properties.

Comment: @zahid See this Answer. => http://stackoverflow.com/a/7412643/325521 It walks you through doing this step-by-step with screenshots. I think you are missing the `FilePath` variable in your `For Each` Enumerator and in the `Excel Connection Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Foreach Loop Editor:

```
Collection>Folder
Collection>Files
```

Your file should not have a particular file name, for multiple excel use `*.xlsx`.

Edit:

Use a Script task to Debug. Map the value of ForEach to a variable and display it through Script task.
Edit the script task with below code.

```
MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["Variable"].Value.ToString());
```

Also, Please check your Source Excel connetion is configured correctly with values coming from foreach.

Comment: Checked,but everything seems fine..I added the screenshot of that now,please have a look

Comment: Debug the code with script task. To see the file names are coming. Edited the answer.