# SSIS Variable use issue in Data Flow

Tags: sql-server, excel, variables, ssis, filepath

At the beginning of the project I created 3 variables with `Scope size Package`:

[image]

I then created a `SQL EXECUTE TASK`:

[image]

Checking this query on SQL SERVER returns:

[image]

Setting EXCEL source as the variable which will get the file location:

[image]

Now on SSIS, I checked both ways
64bit debugging as true and as false. But rest of execution works when it is false, therefore I changed it back to false and saved it.

[image]

This is the Flow of project:

[image]

Whenever I Execute, it gives me this error:

[image]

How to resolve this error. It has taken my whole day but i am still clueless about it. I am new to SSIS. Help will be appreciated.

---

Edited:

Please see the result set of `SQL EXECUTE TASK`:

[image]

Comment: Kindly provide the screenshot for `ResultSet` options in `Execute SQL Task`

Comment: How about delay validation = true on the excel connection?

Comment: You may have to adjust the excel version in the connection manager. I ran into this yesterday. Although I was pointing at an excel file that was created with the 2016 version, the author had saved the file at a lower version number. The task only worked when the excel version was set to 2007-2010 in the connection manager.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package  it is very helpful

Comment: @manderson and @Viki888, i added the screenshot of result set. Please see and check what is the issue. I also tried after changing the `DelayValidation = False`. It is giving the same error still.

Comment: @Hadi , i figured that out on my own even before going dynamic and it is working when the variables are given file paths directly. 
I want to fetch the path from the database -> store it in variable -> use variable on excel connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed that the `DelayValidation` is `False` in your `Excel Connection String`.

You have to make `DelayValidation=TRUE` for both `Excel Connection String` and the `Data Flow Task` within which the excel connection is used.

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: i added the screenshot of result set. Please see and check what is the issue. I also tried after changing the DelayValidation = False. It is giving the same error still.
[See here](http://imgur.com/a/3rJxx)

Answer (score 4):

After alot of struggle i've resolved the issue, but i am really thankful to the people who have given me some extra knowledge about this Tool and some of their guidance must have worked as well at some point as i have set my things accordingly.

what i did at last, which made it work and running were:

1) In package property, under `Execution` set `DelayValidation` to `True`. After following:

(Above, Viki helped me also by setting property `DelayValidation` to `True`, but in `Excel Connection Manager` which counts.)

Comment: you have to accept his answer if he is the one who solved our issue

Answer (score 3):

When Building your *ExcelFilePath* in an expression (or any part of it I guess), make sure the "combination of" variables contains the full path to reach the file, otherwise you will not be able to open the excel source, since it does not find a file.(should be fine at runtime).

Secondly it could be that the values that was used in the original file is not the same in the "new file/next file". Meaning excel wants to convert the column from Unicode to double-precision float or something.

Try adding this in your ConnectionString in the properties window.

IMEX=1

like "*;HDR=YES;***IMEX=1***";

This could help with these types of mixed columns where it contains numbers and alpha values (causing conversion issues).

HTH

Comment: i tried your way, also see the rest of the property settings of this connection.

 [link](http://imgur.com/a/3rJxx)

still the same error occurs.

Comment: Do any other excel loads work on the machine? might be a excel driver issue. Mine stopped working when I got a newer version of office installed.

Comment: when i directly provide path directory to the variable. it works fine completely and loads data correctly in database (the same excel version with same data in same format).

Comment: Try changing the "ServerName" option in the expression to be "ExcelFilePath" instead.

Comment: bro, see the image link again on the first comment of this answer. i did change it and tried this too "excel file path"