# SSIS - looping through excel files using dynamic file name and sheet name

Tags: excel, ssis

I am try to load multiple excel files into database, I have tried this link:

[How to loop through Excel files and load them into a database using SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package/7412643#7412643?newreg=3321d792d07444a68edf9caeb4898b76)

but it keeps looping through the files and never ends.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is not likely given you have a small number of files which you should when testing.
You need to log the file names inside the ForLoop and see if the values are ever changing.
With the dynamic sheet name may have a stability problem, e.g. some characters may not be able to be picked up by the OLEDB driver. 
This is in general a not recommended practice to process dynamic data.

Comment: I can loop through the files successfully, but when I add the second Foreach Loop, the loop keeps running. What is your recommended method for dynamic sheet name?. I know there are some shell and C# scripting, but my scripting skills are not very good.

Comment: So do you think the solution in that link is wrong?

Comment: Check the mappings @SazanAbdalrhman they claim it does but I an skeptical.

Comment: the mapping in the first ForeachLoop is working, it looks like the second mapping is  not working, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, please log the values set at run time