# SSIS package for import Multiple Excel sheets to DB table with sheetnames

Tags: excel, ssis

I have created a `ssis package` to import multiple excel sheets to database table.

So far, i could import all columns to database table but i need another column that keeps sheetname for the main columns.

I used variable for excel sheet and it is pretty succsessful.

How can i add sheet name as an extra column?

Comment: If your sheetname is in a vairable, add it to your dataflow in a derived column transform, _or_ run an `UPDATE` query afterwards to apply it to your table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through excel file and get sheetname using ssis 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097309/how-to-loop-through-excel-file-and-get-sheetname-using-ssis-2008)

Answer (score -1):

As [Nick mentions in a comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972789/ssis-package-for-import-multiple-excel-sheets-to-db-table-with-sheetnames/61987854#comment109625386_61972789)

> If your sheetname is in a vairable, add it to your dataflow in a derived column transform, *or* run an `UPDATE` query afterwards to apply it to your table

I created a derived column and changed it's size , everything is ok.